# Why is the sizeof operator working differently for some expressions?

Tags: c, operators, sizeof

I know that expressions like `x++` or function calls don't get evaluated in the sizeof operator.

When I ran the below code, I got `4 8 8` as output.
Can somebody explain to me what is actually happening on lines 6,7,8?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x=10;
  double y=10.0;
  printf("%d ",sizeof (x=x+y));    
  printf("%d ",sizeof (y=x+y));     
  printf("%d ",sizeof (x+y));
  return 0;
}
```

I figured out that if an expression contains an assignment operator `=` implicitly (like pre-increment) or explicitly (like `x=x+y`) , then the expression doesn't get evaluated in the `sizeof` operator.

Am I right?

Comment: A double may be a different size than an int. You are seeing the size of the type of variable that the expression is. The first is sizeof(int) while the second and third are sizeof(double)

Comment: What are the sizes of `int` and `double` in your platform?

Comment: I know that the sizeof (double) is 8 bytes and sizeof (int) is 4 bytes.

Comment: Note that `%d` is the wrong format specifier for `size_t`, which is the type returned from `sizeof()`.  The correct format specifier is `%zu`.

Comment: Tip: a good well enabled compiler will warn about type mis-match with `printf("%d ",sizeof (x+y));`  This suggest you are compiling without all warnings enabled.  Save time. Enable more warnings.

Comment: C or C++. Pick one. Since you `#include <stdio.h>`, it seems your question is about C (and I thus removed the C++ tag). The `sizeof` operator works on the *type* of the expression, and the types of those expressions in your example are (subtly) **different** for C and C++. That is one of the reasons why we generally frown on questions tagged for both languages.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is _the usual arithmetic conversions_, see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof` operator operates on the datatype of the argument. In your code

- expression `(x=x+y)` yields a type `int`, same as `x`
- expression `(y=x+y)` yields a type `double`, same as `y`
- expression `x+y` yields a type `double`, as per usual arithmetic conversion rules.

The sizes are calculated based on this.

In your platform, it's likely that `sizeof(int)` is `4` and `sizeof(double)` is `8`, so you're seeing corresponding output.

That said, `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, you must use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Comment: Technically, I think the expressions yield types `int&`, `double&`, and `double`. `sizeof` gives the same results of course.

Comment: @cigien why `&`?

Comment: I believe operator =

Comment: Because the type returned by `operator=` is an l-value reference.

Comment: I would clarify that `sizeof(x=x+y)` is the same as `sizeof(x)`.

Comment: @cigien I don't think that you can look at it that way for built-in types, you just get the lvalue directly. Though it behaves equivalently. Like dereferencing a `T*` is a `T` and not a `T&`. In any case, `sizeof(T) == sizeof(T&)`. You can't get the size of a reference type, you always get the size of the referred type instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree about the sizeof. But if it's not an l-value reference, then how does chaining `x=y=z` work even for built-in types?

Comment: Ah, the CPP part. Obviously.

Comment: @cigien It just evaluates to the same lvalue as the assigned-to operand. Consider that these operators are inherited from C, where there are no references.

Comment: Well, now the c++ tag has been removed, so the difference is moot :p

Comment: @rustyx What confused me about the linked example is why `decltype(x)` doesn't also print `int&`. Turns out the difference between the two outputs is that `decltype` behaves differently when given an identifier than when given any other kind of expression. If you add parenthesis around `x` (`decltype((x))`) you get the uniform behavior that `decltype` treats all lvalue expressions as rvalue references.

Comment: @rustyx That is also an artifact of `decltype`. It always adds a reference in that case even if the type isn't a reference. The confusion is that lvalue is a value category and lvalue reference is a type. Value categories and types have a little bit of overlap but are generally distinct concepts. The only way to represent value category as a type is to encode it in a reference with either rvalue references or lvalue references which is why `decltype` adds it. Otherwise there is no way to categorize the value category of an expression as a type.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` evaluates the type.

`x` is an `int` and seems to have the size of **4 bytes** on your system.

`y` is a `double` and seems to have the size of **8 bytes** on your system.

`sizeof (x+y)` will evaluate to the largest of the two, thereby `double` and **8 bytes**.

`x=x+y` is is still an `int` as there will be a conversion to `int` type from the `double` `x+y`.

Thereby `sizeof (x=x+y)` is **4 bytes**.

`y=x+y` is still an `double` as `x+y` is of the type `double`.

Thereby `sizeof (y=x+y)` is **8 bytes**.

Comment: `x=x+y` does not contain a conversion to `int` from the `double` `y`. In `x+y`, `x` is converted to `double`. Then `x+y` is a `double`, and that is converted to `int` for the assignment. (All as if the expression would be evaluated.)

Answer (score -2):

Expressions are evaluated, just results of those evaluations differ:

```
x=x+y
```

can be readed as:

```
int = float + int
```

What happens is, that result is calculated and then turncated to int and therefore you get the result 4: sizeof(int) = 4.

Second line is simmilar but with float.

On the last line you calculate sizeof (float + int) which is equal to sizeof(float) = 8.

Comment: No, expressions of line 6 and 7 isn't get evaluated.

Comment: Expressions won't get evaluated, kindly edit your answer.

Comment: You are right, no expression is evaluated, sizeof returns size of what would be evaluated. Editing my answer won't make much sense now